# Cancel multiple download tasks react-native-blob-util

Tags: javascript, react-native, promise

I'm trying to push download tasks in the array and cancel them on click, but it seems that the pushed tasks are not available in the outer scope.

```
  let downloadTasks: StatefulPromise<FetchBlobResponse>[] = [];
```

Start downloads

```
const handleDownloadOfflineData = async () => {
    try {
          await Promise.all(
            uniqueMediaFiles.map((media, i) => {

              const task = ReactNativeBlobUtil.config({
                path: `${cacheDir}/${INTERACTIVE_TOUR_DIR}/${oneInteractiveTourDetailsMobile.id}/media/${media.bucketPath}`,
              })
                .fetch('GET', `${BUCKET_PATH}${media.bucketPath}`)
                .progress((received, total) => {
                  //..
                  console.log('Progress: ', received / total);
                });
              downloadTasks.push(task); //Push the task
              console.log('PUSH TASK: ', downloadTasks.length);
              return task;
            }),
          ).then(async _responses => {
            //..
          });
    } catch (err) {
      //..
    }
  };
```

Cancel tasks

```
  const handleCancelDownload = async () => {
    console.log('CANCEL TASKS: ', downloadTasks.length);
    downloadTasks.forEach(task => {
      task.cancel();
    });
  };
```

When I click on the button to cancel tasks once the download has started, I get this from console logs

```
PUSH TASK:  1
PUSH TASK:  2
PUSH TASK:  3
PUSH TASK:  4
PUSH TASK:  5
PUSH TASK:  6
Progress:  1
Progress:  1
Progress:  1
Progress:  1
Progress:  1
Progress:  0.0023231438670363127
CANCEL TASKS:  0
```

As you can see, the tasks are pushed to the array, but in the cancel downloads function, the array is still empty, and I cannot cancel them.

How do I make it work?

Comment: mine download progress does not persist in case of multiple downloads it flickers in the progress bar, also I couldn't find a solution to stop it.

Comment: @Digamber negi Check my answer, I managed to fix it eventually. Canceling tasks and mutiple downloads works fine. There is a bug where the last progress of the last downloading item is not updated, but the easy fix is to just force the progress to be 100% once everything is downloaded. Also the progress is calculated correctly since it reports the dotal downloaded size, and not how much it downloaded from last update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it by changing the downloadTasks variable to a ref:

```
const downloadTasks = useRef<StatefulPromise<FetchBlobResponse>[]>([]);


const handleDownloadOfflineData = async () => {
    try {
          await Promise.all(
            uniqueMediaFiles.map((media, i) => {
              let lastReceived = 0;
              const task = ReactNativeBlobUtil.config({
                path: `${cacheDir}/${INTERACTIVE_TOUR_DIR}/${oneInteractiveTourDetailsMobile.id}/media/${media.bucketPath}`,
              })
                .fetch('GET', `${BUCKET_PATH}${media.bucketPath}`)
                .progress((received, total) => {
                  setDownloadedProgress(prev => {
                  return prev + Number(received) - lastReceived;
                });
                lastReceived = Number(received);
                });
              downloadTasks.current = [...downloadTasks.current, task];
              console.log('PUSH TASK: ', downloadTasks.length);
              return task;
            }),
          ).then(async _responses => {
            setHasDownloadedContent(true);
            setIsOfflineContentUpToDate(true);
            setIsDownloading(false);
            setDownloadedProgress(totalDownloadSize); //Fixes missing progress for last file
          });
    } catch (err) {
      //..
    }
  };
```

```
 const handleCancelDownload = async () => {
    try {
      downloadTasks.current.forEach(task => {
        task.cancel();
      });
      downloadTasks.current = [];
      setDownloadedProgress(0);
      setHasDownloadedContent(false);
      setIsOfflineContentUpToDate(undefined);

      const path = `${ReactNativeBlobUtil.fs.dirs.CacheDir}/${INTERACTIVE_TOUR_DIR}/${data?.oneInteractiveTourDetailsMobile.id}_${contentLocale}`;
      if (!(await ReactNativeBlobUtil.fs.exists(path))) {
        return;
      }
      await ReactNativeBlobUtil.fs.unlink(path);
    } catch (err) {
      Toast.show({
        text1: t('toast.error.deleteDownloadFailed'),
        text2: t('toast.error.deleteDownloadFailed.tryOptions'),
        type: 'error',
      });
    }
  };
```

Comment: let me try if this could work